# Spring Security antMatchers UUID

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to disable the authentification for a resource with spring security. The resource url includes an java uuid. My matcher doesnt match the uuid.

```
web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/tobaccos/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$");
```

This snippet matches all behind the /tobaccos. But I just want to match for example /tobaccos/4da42fa2-4fad-4c7f-af77-1d7890741009

How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to employ `regexMatchers()` to use regex (as in your case), and not `antMatchers()` (which expects [Ant Patterns](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)).

Also, `^` does not seem to be needed in the middle.

```
web.ignoring().regexMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/tobaccos/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$");
```

This will match any /tobaccos/$UUID URL (ending in $UUID).

```
web.ignoring().regexMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/tobaccos/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}/.*");
```

Will also allow something after the UUID.